# Why happen error [ GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user 401 (Unauthorized) ] on axios with react

Tags: reactjs

I using laravel with react and I wanna use databases data.

But show error of title.

I'm in login on laravel and Checked users data is exist in db.

I have no idea what's wrong.

please give me advice.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

function User() {
    
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        getUsers()
    },[])
    
    const getUsers = async () => {
        try{
        const response = await axios.get('/api/user') ;
        setUsers(response.data.users)
        } catch(e) {
        if(e.response.status === 401) {
            const response = {};
            this.setState({ response });
        }
        }
    }
```

[image]